# Internet Explorer Driver and Webdriver.io

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

I've done everything I can to get internet explorer working with webdriver.io but there is one part that is very confusing.

Step 1: Download internet explorer driver here: http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ (The file is a .exe and is called 'IEDriverServer.exe')

Step 2: No need to run the executable, just put it in an easily accessible folder and remember the path to that folder.

Step 3: Quoting from the documentation here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver 
This is what I need to do: 
"The standalone server executable must be downloaded from the Downloads page and placed in your PATH."

I see tons of info about how to do this in java, but nothing about how to do it in webdriver.io. Just editing the path in environment variables does not do the trick and it doesn't really make sense to do that.

Comment: Doesn't webdriver.io expect Selenium to already be running? See e.g. http://webdriver.io/guide.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, exactly a selenium standalone server must be started in another terminal.

Comment: Then *"how to do this in java"* is just **how to do it**, surely?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Yes, I guess I have to somehow set the path when I run the jar file?

Comment: Oh wow. Here's the answer (even though the question pertains to Chrome): https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.8.0.jar -Dwebdriver.edge.driver=[[INSERT PATH TO DRIVER HERE]]
```

See comment here from "Milind Diwakar":

https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/23/bringing-automated-testing-to-microsoft-edge-through-webdriver/

Answer (score 0):

These problems may result from compatibility errors:

This command will install IE driver 32bits version 3.0.0

```
.\node_modules\.bin\selenium-standalone install --drivers.ie.arch=ia32 --version=3.0.0 --drivers.ie.baseURL=https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com
```

This command will start IE driver 32bits version 3.0.0

```
.\node_modules\.bin\selenium-standalone start --drivers.ie.arch=ia32 --version=3.0.0 --drivers.ie.baseURL=https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com
```